# Tooltip image on cell hover, Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm currently working on a Google Spreadsheet that has to include a bunch of image references.

What I want to achieve is this: When you hover over a cell an image appear (like a tooltip).

I found [this widget](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/image) on the Google Developers, but when I add the code to my spreadsheet nothing happens.

Does any of you guys know how to do something like this? Any hints on how to go about this is highly appreciated!

Comment: I think I am trying to have a similar feature as you. I opened a thread about it here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/E6OhUN2q5Pk;context-place=forum/docs in the official forum. I propose 2nd way to accomplish the effect of hovering on cells, but not sure if it makes sense to you too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are wanting to do is not possible in a Google Spreadsheet, widgets are only available in UiApp or HTML service.

What should be doable is to recreate the spreadsheet display in a Ui and from there use some kind of popup with a mouseOver handler to show the images as you want.

Depending of your use case - mainly on what spreadsheet specific features you want to have when looking at your data - this could be a good or bad solution but only you can answer this last point.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I think it would be a case of shooting birds with cannons if it's not easily implementable.

Comment: Can you implement system-logic with the widgets? I would like to have a interface which shows you item; let you answer to it; store your answer; iterates this one. I opened another thread about it https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/E6OhUN2q5Pk;context-place=forum/docs in the official Google from.

Answer (score 5):

Displaying a User Interface from a Spreadsheet

As an alternative to deploying your user interface as a standalone web app, you can create a container-bound script from a Spreadsheet, and display the user interface from the Spreadsheet. To do this, find your doGet function and simply replace the call to

```
 return app;
```

with the following:

```
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 spreadsheet.show(app);
```

where app is the variable name for the UiInstance object you are returning. Additionally, when you display the user interface from a Spreadsheet, the function does not have to be named doGet. You could instead call it something like displayMyUi, and then call that function directly to display the user interface in your Spreadsheet. When a user interface is displayed from a Spreadsheet, the script runs as the user who's accessing the Spreadsheet.

e.g.

```
 function doGet() {
 var app = UiApp.createApplication();
 // The very first Google Doodle!
 app.add(app.createImage("http://www.google.com/logos/googleburn.jpg"));

 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 spreadsheet.show(app);
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide any examples about your codes in practice, please. I am trying to have QA format but not sure if it can be done with Google Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

So probably not the cleanest solution, but you can add links to a cell, and when you add a link to an image from your google drive (probably you should make the image avaiable to all with the link) then on mouseover you get a tooltip like box, with preview