# Google Sheet Tooltip Integer Difference By Column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatting, cell

[image]
As I insert new data from the top rows down, I would like to have a tooltip that shows the difference in an integer or percentage of the previous cell column (not row).  Does anyone know how this can be done programmatically?

For example, under BXY if I was to hover above 52.41 I should see a difference of +12.69 or its equivalent in percentage format based on the fact that on the previous day, the original integer was 39.72.

Comment: After checking in the documentation and in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740798), it seems doing just a script for a tooltip cannot be done without using a more complex setting like a webApp. I would suggest having a script that keeps track of the difference with the previous row in the same column. For example, if `BXY` has the 52.41 added, a row above it can have something like "change of +12.69", that you could do with apps script quite easily, is that an acceptable strategy?

Comment: @AMolina ANYTHING is acceptable. do you have a resource or code i can try?

Comment: If you can provide a sanitized copy of your sheet I can help you out with the code.

Comment: @AMolina https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Iy9lbvwjn3HVO-OkEFECJYTETEhYrsiUOJzi7zOFo_4/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function check(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = ss.getRange("A6:H7").getValues();
  var response = [];
  var test;
  var sum;

  for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++){
    sum = (data[0][i] - data[1][i])
    sum = sum.toFixed(3);
    response.push("Change of " + sum)
  }
  Logger.log(response);
  ss.getRange("A5:H5").setValues([response])
}
```

I tested it with the sheet you provided and it writes the change in the row above the numbers, hope it's of assistance. You can set the script to be run on a trigger as you need it, time-based or based on the Sheet activity, [here is some documentation about them](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).

Comment: About to give it a shot now!

Comment: @Fdwillis I'm glad it got solved! Please consider marking the answer as accepted to mark the question as solved.